# Find number value assigned to checkbox from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have an ASP.NET MVC razor page that has a loop and in the loop a `CheckboxFor`. I am assigning a number value to each of these checkboxes. I also assigned a class so that I can catch an onchange event in jquery when any one of these checkbox value's has changed:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.PrincipleInvestigator, new { Value = item.ProjectResearcherId, @class = "Principle-investigator-checkbox" })
```

Then, in jquery, i want the number value of the specific checkbox that was clicked:

```
$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").change(function () {
    alert($(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").val);
});
```

This is does not work. I don't actually know how to identify which checkbox in the list was clicked. Something like `this.val` ? Also, I'm not sure that `.val` is gives me the number value I assigned it, but if I inspect the rendered HTML, the value can be seen:

```
<input value="4570" class="Principle-investigator-checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The PrincipleInvestigator field is required." id="item_PrincipleInvestigator" name="item.PrincipleInvestigator" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: It's `$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").val()` and not `$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").val`

Comment: Also, handle the `click` event instead of `change`. It works better for `checkboxes`.

Comment: Also, within the event handler, you can refer to the element by `$(this)`. You don't need to repeat the selector, and it will refer to the element receiving the event, and not the first one (in case you have more than one sharing the same `class`).

Comment: A good way to start understanding `jQuery` is by reading this: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);
    //or  alert($(this).val());
    //avoid alert($(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").val());
});
```

**this.value**

Here, `this` refers to the native DOM element, so we can refer the native DOM property `value` to get the value

**$(this).val()**

Here we are wrapping the native DOM element with jQuery object. Hence we need to use the methods on the jQuery wrapper object to get the value. That is 
[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

***avoid alert($(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").val())***

val() is a getter method and it will always return a first matched element and not all the elements. It is always better to use `this` inside a change function when you are dealing with multiple element selector.

Comment: +1. It's good to mention that if you use the selector again within the event handler, it will return the first element in the list (when multiple are returned).

Comment: its class selector it it will return value of all i think so

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, No. Check document link provided `Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element`. You can try yourself

Answer (score 1):

`$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox")` will select all checkboxes with this class as there are multiple checbkxes,you have to write `$(this)` to get current clikced one value  using clicked one reference like this:

```
$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").change(function () {
    alert($(this).val()); //gets value of current checkbox which caused event
});
```

Also `val` is not a function it is `val()`

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a method not an attribute
use `val()` instead of `val`

```
$(".Principle-investigator-checkbox").change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Also use `$(this)` inside the event handler. Other wise it will take the value of  first element with class `.Principle-investigator-checkbox`.